# Augmented Dickey-Fuller - mismatch between R packages

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

The Augmented Dickey-Fuller test is used to check whether a series has any detectable trend or drift.  It is commonly used as a test of stationarity (the alternative hypothesis).  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test), the test typically involves three sub-tests covering the various combinations of drift and trend.

The test is independently implemented in two R packages: aTSA and tseries.  However, for the dataset I'm dealing with, the two functions give very different values:

```
> aTSA::adf.test(my.data)
Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test 
alternative: stationary 

Type 1: no drift no trend 
     lag   ADF p.value
[1,]   0 -1.36    0.19
[2,]   1 -2.93    0.01
[3,]   2 -3.12    0.01
[4,]   3 -3.21    0.01
Type 2: with drift no trend 
     lag   ADF p.value
[1,]   0 -1.34  0.5735
[2,]   1 -2.90  0.0524
[3,]   2 -3.10  0.0347
[4,]   3 -3.17  0.0281
Type 3: with drift and trend 
     lag   ADF p.value
[1,]   0 -1.60  0.7351
[2,]   1 -3.25  0.0870
[3,]   2 -3.56  0.0432
[4,]   3 -3.52  0.0468
---- 
Note: in fact, p.value = 0.01 means p.value <= 0.01 

> tseries::adf.test(my.data)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  my.data
Dickey-Fuller = -2.8353, Lag order = 4, p-value = 0.2357
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

You'll note that the tseries result, -2.8353, doesn't appear anywhere in the aTSA result set, let alone at lag=4.

A simple test suggests that the tseries output corresponds to the type-3 test result, and usually matches perfectly well:

```
> x <- rnorm(100)
> lag <- 4
> aTSA::adf.test(x, output=FALSE)$type3[lag+1,"ADF"]
     ADF 
-5.74654 
> tseries::adf.test(x)$statistic
Dickey-Fuller 
     -5.74654
```

So it looks like I've just hit on an interesting (as in "interesting times") dataset.

What statistical properties of the data could give rise to this kind of discrepancy?  How can I reconcile the two ADF functions' results?

There's a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168355), but the accepted answer doesn't actually explain what could give rise to the difference, it just suggests that there shouldn't **be** a difference.

Comment: Missing values?

Answer (score 0):

The Adf test handles serial correlation by introducing lagged terms of Δyt, so it needs a lag order.

If you look at the summary of tseries::adf.test(my.data), you'll see that Lag order = 4.
But in aTSA::adf.test(my.data), the maximum delay is 3.
So if you add the nlag argument to the previous function (nlag = 5 in your case), you'll get the same results.