# Augmented Dickey Fuller implementation: about regression terms and embed() function

Tags: unit-root, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

In relation to already posted question:

[The difference between the three Augmented Dickey–Fuller test (none,drift, trend)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131148/the-difference-between-the-three-augmented-dickey-fuller-test-none-drift-trend)

and specifically to the details given by Graeme Walsh's (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/24617/graeme-walsh) answer, I still miss something about the use of the embed() function and its way to arrange data in a matrix fashion. As we can see from the following dummy example:

```
> s <- 1:6
> embed(s,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    4    3    2
[3,]    5    4    3
[4,]    6    5    4
```

Considering the same piece of code shown in related question at link above:

```
data(sunspots)
x           <- sunspots
alternative <- "stationary"
k           <- trunc((length(x) - 1)^(1/3))

k <- k + 1          # Number of lagged differenced terms
y <- diff(x)        # First differences
n <- length(y)      # Length of first differenced series
z <- embed(y, k)    # Used for creating lagged series

yt  <- z[, 1]       # First differences
xt1 <- x[k:n]       # Series in levels - the first k-1 observations are dropped
tt  <- k:n          # Time-trend
yt1 <- z[, 2:k]     # Lagged differenced series - there are k-1 of them
```

Hence, `yt <- z[, 1]` stores observations "older" than the ones stored inside `yt1 <- z[, 2:k]` while comparing same row indexes between `yt` and `yt1`. At the same time, with constant and time-trend regression, the formula is:

```
                  yt ~ xt1 + 1 + tt + yt1
```

I mean `yt` (also) dependent upon `yt1`.

Would it be possible to clarify this aspect ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I overlooked the timeline. Indexes in time series start from old observations (first index) up to the newest one (last index). Hence `yt[idx,1]` stores a more recent observation than `yt[idx, 2:k]`, for each index `idx`.